# Named credential now working when deployed to production org via package

Tags: apex, administration, namedcredentials

When testing in the scratch org environments everything goes fine, but after creating a package and installing it in a environment that is close to production, callouts are not working, and the following error is shown:

```
An Apex error occurred: System.UnexpectedException: Script-thrown exception
```

Hardcoding the auth header makes the callouts work, so it's clear that the problem is from the named credential.

Any tips on how to treat named credentials when they are wished to be deployed within a package?

Comment: See answer by Alex B in the referenced Q&A

Comment: It seems like this resolved the problem. Thanks.